# How to extend javascript scrolling nav bar with different blade files in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a problem with extend my nav bar blade file with different blade files. I have following nav bar blade file working with id in scrolling methods
_nav.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div id="nav-close" class="fas fa-times"></div>
    <a href="#home">home</a>
    <a href="#idea">Idea</a>
    <a href="#about">about</a>
    <a href="#packages">packages</a>
    <a href="#reviews">reviews</a>
    <a href="#contact">contact</a>
    <a href="#video">video</a>
</nav>
```

and My Nav bar scrolling pages are available in main.blade.php file like this way
main.blade.php

```
<section class="home" id="home">

</section>

<section class="home" id="idea">

</section>

<section class="home" id="about">

</section>

<section class="home" id="packages">

</section>
```

and I extend my _nav blade file with main blade like this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
@include('partials._nav')
    </head>


    <body>
//contains go here
</body>
</html>
```

now I need extend my _nav blade file with another blade view like city.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
@include('partials._nav')
</head>
<body>

// city containt goes here
</body>
</html>
```

and web.php like

```
Route::get('/city', function () {
    return view('city');
});
```

but when I go to city view my nav bar is showing but not scrolling with like main.blade.php file how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't place my navigation in the `<head>` but in the `<body>`

Comment: @brombeer is it solution for my problem?